# Libgdx drawing a circle with large radius causes exception

Tags: libgdx

When drawing a circle using the ShapeRenderer and using a really big radius (in millions, planet/sun size, given in metres) libgdx throws an exception

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20003
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.color(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:116)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.circle(ShapeRenderer.java:880)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.circle(ShapeRenderer.java:844)
    at com.kacpr.solar.system.Planet.draw(Planet.java:74)
    at com.kacpr.solar.system.SolarSystem.render(SolarSystem.java:66)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

This didn't happen when I used smaller values.
The question I have is whether I'm doing something wrong using such high numbers for a radius and should scale this down before drawing (I use this radius for some other calculations) or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of segments used to draw a circle is something like `6 × cube root (radius)`. This means for a sufficiently large radius you will break the number of allocated vertices in the `ShapeRenderer`, which is defaulted to 5000 I think.

One approach could be to scale everything down by some factor before drawing it. Another approach would be to use the other overload of `circle` that accept an argument that indicates the number of segments to use and tweak that value.